# Number of ways of partitioning a union of $n$ sets

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, set-partition

Suppose $E=A+B$ is the union of two sets $A$ and $B$.Then, we can have $4$ ways of partitioning $E$ into disjoint subsets: $\{AB,A∆B\},\{B, A\bar B\},\{A,\bar A B \},\{AB,A\bar B,\bar AB\}$ which is straightforward to identify from the Venn diagram as non-overlapping regions, the smallest such regions being $AB,A\bar B $ and $ \bar AB\ $. However I am unable to get any clue on how to generalize this to $3$ or more sets (becaus eit gets very clumsy to use Venn diagrams for the purpose): in case of $3$ sets there are $7$ smallest possible disjoint subsets. I guess there should be $\geq 8$ ways of partitioning this set. In fact there should be $2^n-1$ smallest possible disjoint subsets of the union $E_n=A_1+A_2+...+A_n$ and there should be, in fact the $\geq 2^n$ partitions possible for $E_n$. However, this is just a guess, I believe that this could be wrong. But i couldn't find anything relating to this on the net or any of my textbooks, except that it is related to Boolean factorisation and consensus sets. So, any reference would be helpful.

### Edit

The number of such partitions must be more than $2^n$. For the case $n=3$ here are some of the desired partitions:
[image]

### Update $-1$

As I understand $P=\{E_1, E_2, ..., E_l \}$ is a partition of $E$ iff all the $E_i$'s are non-empty, $E_iE_j=\emptyset$ for all pairs $i\neq j$ and $E_1 + E_2 + ... + E_l = E$. Now, any set $E_{ij} = E_i + E_j$ will still be disjoint with the remaining $l-2$ subsets of $E$ and hence forms another partition with them. In this way there are $\text{C}(l,2)$ ways to form partitions of size $l-1$ from $P$ viz. $\{ E_1,E_2,...,E_{i-1},E_{i+1},...,E_{j-1},E_{j+1},...,E_l \}$. Applying the formula recursively we find the total number of partitions of decreasing size to be $\text{C}(l,2)\text{C}(l-1,2)...\text{C}(2,2) + 1 = \frac{l!(l-1)!}{2^{l-1}}+1$. But for an $n$-union set $E=E_n$, $l=2^n -1$. In this way, the desired number is $56701$ for $n=3$ and $6958057668962400001$ for $n=4$, much larger than what @joriki has answered.

### Update $-2$

Seems my above analysis is partly wrong. For $P = \{ E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4\}$, the different partitions are: $1$ partition of type $\{E_i,E_j,E_k,E_l\}$ corresponding to $(1+1+1+1)$, $\text{C}(4,2)=6$ partitions of type $\{E_i+E_j,E_k,E_l\}$ corresponding to $(2+1+1)$, $\text{C}(4,2)/2=3$ partitions of type $\{E_i+E_j,E_k+E_l\}$ corresponding to $(2+2)$,$\text{C}(4,3)=4$ partitions of type $\{E_i+E_j+E_k,E_l\}$ corresponding to $(3+1)$ and the total number is $14$. Now the number for some $P=\{E_1,...,E_{2^n -1}\}$ is desired, which is exactly $B_{2^n-1}-1$.

Comment: Use `\cdots` to get a vertically centered and properly spaced ellipsis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to count the (equivalence classes of) expressions that can be used to partition general sets, irrespective of whether any of the resulting subsets are actually non-empty for any particular sets, i.e. whether these formally distinct expressions actually correspond to distinct partitions of any particular sets. However, judging from your example and your count of $2^n-1$, you do want to exclude expressions like $\bar A\bar B$ that yield empty subsets for all $A$ and $B$. Also, contrary to convention, you’re apparently not counting $\{E\}$ as a partition of $E$.

As you say, given $n$ sets $A_n$, there are $2^n-1$ different products of the sets and their complements, since for each set you can include either the set or its complement, yielding $n$ binary choices, and the product with only complements is to be excluded because it yields an empty set for any $A_n$.

Every formal partition expression can be expressed as a partition of these products. The number of partitions of a set with $k$ labeled elements is given by the [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Set_partitions) $B_k$. We need to subtract one again because you’re not counting $\{E\}$ as a partition of $E$. Thus, the number of (equivalence classes of) expressions that can be used to partition a union of $n$ sets in the desired sense is $B_{2^n-1}-1$. Here’s a table of the first few values:

\begin{array}{r|r}
n&B_{2^n-1}-1\\\hline
1&0
\\
2&4
\\
3&876
\\
4&1382958544
\\
5&10293358946226376485095652
\end{array}

The Bell numbers grow very roughly as $n^n$ (see the Wikipedia article for more precise asymptotics), so your counts grow very roughly as $\left(2^n\right)^{2^n}=2^{n\cdot2^n}$.